# can DISTINCT be overridden (or lose its special power)

Tags: mysql

This query gives me **639 records**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT lnk.lnk_ID, dmg.dmg_Sex, dlk.scot_Type
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = dlk.dlk_lnkID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID 
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '01/01/2015' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '01/01/2016' 
AND     dlk.scot_Type = 'Enquiry'
ORDER BY lnk.lnk_ID
```

now I add `dlk.enq_region` which is of the same table as `dlk.scot_Type`,
Only this time I get **644 records**.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT lnk.lnk_ID, dmg.dmg_Sex, dlk.scot_Type,
        dlk.enq_region,             
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = dlk.dlk_lnkID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID 
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '01/01/2015' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '01/01/2016' 
AND     dlk.scot_Type = 'Enquiry'
ORDER BY lnk.lnk_ID
```

How is this possible. It seems like its not using `DISTINCT` on the second query, because there are infact a few `lnk.lnk_ID` that have double entries.

Im sorry, but I cant put down a structure.

Comment: show example of your data. Keep in mind that distinct is used along the whole row. Apparently some of your rows joins with different lnk_IDs

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I hear what you are saying, but the field that I append is not a index field, so it should not change the linkage in any way, but I get this result. Will be tricky to get some data on here, but I'll try

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Ah infact... that field `dlk.scot_Type` is indeed indexed. So will that cause the problem perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is confusing about this?

You added a column and you are getting 5 more rows.

That means that one or more combinations of `lnk.lnk_ID, dmg.dmg_Sex, dlk.scot_Type` have more than one region.  This seems obvious.

You can readily see what they are using `group by`:

```
SELECT lnk.lnk_ID, dmg.dmg_Sex, dlk.scot_Type,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dlk.enq_region) as enq_regions
FROM DAILY_LINK dlk JOIN
     Link lnk
     ON lnk.lnk_ID = dlk.dlk_lnkID JOIN
     Demographic dmg
     ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID 
WHERE dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015-01-101' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2016-01-01' AND
      dlk.scot_Type = 'Enquiry'
GROUP BY lnk.lnk_ID, dmg.dmg_Sex, dlk.scot_Type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dlk.enq_region) > 1;
```

Comment: Well, no it does not. it is an exact double entry, Same ID same SEX same REGION.

Comment: @morne Gordon's answer is legitimate - this is very likely the cause of your issue.  However, I think you're looking for a group by clause (see below).

Comment: Okay thanks. I just have a slight different problem. This is for a 4D database and its a scaled down version of mySQL that they used. It seems like `GROUP_CONCAT` is not part of that scaled down version.
I get a error when I include it in the query.

Comment: @morne . . . Remove the `group_concat` and just focus on the values in the columns that are returned.  Then you can look them up manually.